# GCC (trunk) -fanalyzer [CWE-401] false positive?

Tags: c, gcc, static-analysis

I recently learned about GCC's new -fanalyzer feature, and decided to try it out on some of our codebase. The results were quite interesting, but there's one function where i suspect a false positive.

This is the function in question, for which GCC reported a malloc-leak ([see here](https://godbolt.org/z/xFVuvN)):

```
char** va_to_argv(va_list args, int32_t* argc)
{
    va_list a;
    char* arg;
    int32_t n;
    int32_t l;
    int32_t sz = 0;
    int32_t cnt = 0;

    va_copy(a, args);
    while ((arg = va_arg(a, char*)) != NULL)
    {
        sz += strlen(arg) + 1;
        ++cnt;
    }
    va_end(a);

    struct s
    {
        char* argv[cnt + 1];
        char  data[sz];
    };

    struct s* tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(*tmp));

    for (n=0, l=0; n<cnt; ++n)
    {
        tmp->argv[n] = &tmp->data[l];
        strcpy(tmp->argv[n], va_arg(args, char*));
        l += strlen(tmp->argv[n]) + 1;
    }

    tmp->argv[cnt++] = NULL;

    if (argc)
    {
        *argc = cnt;
    }

    return &(tmp->argv[0]);
}
```

It is supposed to convert a `va_list` (containing only `char*`, with `NULL` as the last argument) to the equivalent argc/argv representation. To my knowledge, there have never been any issues involving this particular function, so i was quite surprised when GCC reported `tmp` being leaked at the return statement.

Yes, the result of `calloc()` is stored in tmp, and the function doesn't return `tmp` directly, so at first glance the warning makes sense. However, the value returned is a pointer to the first element of `tmp`, and the address of the first element of a struct is the same as the address of the struct itself (so `free(&(tmp->argv[0]))` should be legal).

> ISO/IEC 9899, Section 6.7.2.1
>
> A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Unfortunately, this code relies on a GCC-specific extension (VLA in struct) which isn't supported by clang. Otherwise i would have liked to cross-check what clang's static analyzer has to say about that.

**EDIT**:

Even though the types don't match (as pointed out by Lundin), the warning persists, even in this version of the function (which of course no longer does anything meaningful):

```
char** va_to_argv(va_list args, int32_t* argc)
{
    struct s
    {
        char** argv;
        char  data[10];
    };

    struct s* tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(*tmp));

    if (tmp == NULL) return NULL;

    return tmp->argv;
}
```

Comment: Why not just return `tmp` ? (either directly, or cast to a `char **` )

Comment: @wildplasser i could do that of course (and when i do, the warning disappears), but returning a pointer to the first element should be legal too.

Comment: BTW: you dont need the struct. you don't need the `char  data[sz];` element, because `argv[0]` points to the start of the whole concatenated string, and the caller wont see it differntly anyway. So, just return `argv[]` as a `(char **)`

Comment: You can get rid of the non-standard VLA easily enough by using a flexible array member instead.

Comment: As for the warning, my take is that it's because neither the struct type or its first member is compatible with `char**`. The first member of the struct is of type `char* argv[cnt + 1];`, not a  `char**`. A pointer to the first member of the struct would rather be type `char* (*)[cnt + 1]`. So it's perhaps not surprising that the analyser can't tell the difference, because you aren't returning a compatible type to what was allocated, nor are you strictly speaking returning a pointer to the initial member.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the advice, i didn't think about the types. However, the issue doesn't seem to be type related, because the warning persists even if i change the `argv` member to `char**` and return `tmp->argv` (and completely remove pretty much everything else: see edit to my original post).

Comment: @Lundin Also, i'm curious how you'd use a flexible array member in this case, given that both members are of variable size?

Comment: Just add a cast, and a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version without the VLA:

---

```
char **va_to_argv(va_list args, int32_t *argc)
{
    va_list a;
    char *arg;
    char *data;
    char **arr;
    int32_t n;
    int32_t ii;
    int32_t sz = 0;
    int32_t cnt = 0;

    va_copy(a, args);
    for(cnt=0;  (arg = va_arg(a, char*)) ; cnt++ )
    {
        sz += 1+ strlen(arg) ;
    }
    va_end(a);


    data = malloc(sz+1);
    arr = calloc(cnt+1, sizeof *arr);

    for (n=ii=0; n<cnt; n++)
    {
        arr[n] = &data[ii];
        strcpy(arr[n], va_arg(args, char*));
        ii += 1 + strlen(arr[n]) ;
    }

    arr[n++] = NULL;

    if (argc) *argc = n;

    return arr;
}
```

---

EDIT: if you want to allocate only one object, you could position the char[] array after the *char[] array, and just return the pointer array:

---

```
arr = malloc(sz+1 + (cnt+1) * sizeof *arr);
data = (char*) ( &arr[cnt+1] ); // Put data after the last arr[] element
```

Comment: Yeah, i thought about doing something like that, but decided against it because it is less convenient for the caller. They have to know that they need to call `free(argv[0])` before calling `free(argv)`, which is something i like to avoid (because it could easily be forgotten, causing a memory leak).

Comment: You could also pack the two arrays into one by allocating them in one malloc() call.